# How to make a docker image for AI created for connect 4

Tags: docker

So I am working on creating a docker image that contains the AI for Connect 4. I have tried looking up tutorials and tried doing code but I am stuck. If you are in the defi space, you might have heard of golem network, I am currently just trying to implement Connect 4 into it. I would truly be happy with any help. Thx

Here is my code for the AI (this is currently not a docker image)

```
C4.AI = function(_game, _player, _strength) {
var _rack = _game.rack;
var _columns = _rack.length;
var _rows = _rack[0].length;
var _best_col = 0;
_player.human = false;


function findAndPlayMove() {
    if (_game.current === _player) {
        // Give the previous move's drop animation some time to finish
        setTimeout(function() {
            var best = alphabeta(_strength, -Infinity, Infinity, _player);
            var r = _game.util.getDropRow(_best_col);
            _game.trigger('drop', { col_index : _best_col });
            _best_col = 0;
        }, 500);
    }
}


function alphabeta(depth, alpha, beta, player) {
    var value = evaluateBoard(player);

    // If maximum search depth is reached or this board is a win/loss we
    // don't need to look further
    if (depth === 0 || value === Infinity || value === -Infinity) {
        return value;
    }

    // Calculate moves for this AI player
    if (player === _player) {
        var scores = [];

        // For each column calculate the max possible score
        // (player tries to maximize)
        for (var c = 0; c < _columns; c++) {
            var r = _game.util.getDropRow(c);

            // This column is already full of coins
            if (r === -1) continue;

            // Temporarily store move
            _rack[c][r] = player;

            // Recursively calculate the best result this move could have
            // for this player
            alpha = Math.max(alpha, alphabeta(depth - 1, alpha, beta, player.opponent));

            // Undo the move
            delete _rack[c][r];
            scores[c] = alpha;

            if (beta <= alpha) break;
        }

        if (depth === _strength) {
            var max_score = -Infinity;
            var last_valid = null;
            for (var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
                // TODO: find out why >= screws up AI
                var score = scores[i];
                if (score > max_score) {
                    max_score = score;
                    _best_col = i;
                }

                if (score) last_valid = i;
            }

            // All moves by player will lead to loss
            // Just pick a valid column
            if (max_score === -Infinity) {
                _best_col = last_valid;
            }
        }

        return alpha;
    } else {
        // For each column calculate the min possible score
        // (opponent tries to minimize)
        for (var c = 0; c < _columns; c++) {
            var r = _game.util.getDropRow(c);
            // This column is already full
            if (r === -1) continue;

            // Temporarily store move
            _rack[c][r] = player;

            // Recursively calculate the best result this move could have
            // for oppponent
            beta = Math.min(beta, alphabeta(depth - 1, alpha, beta, player.opponent));

            // Undo the move
            delete _rack[c][r];

            // If the opponent's score for this column is <= to our player's
            // maximum there's no need to further explore this branch: it
            // would never lead to a better score
            if (beta <= alpha) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return beta;
    }
}


/* ################################################################################
    UTILITIES
################################################################################ */


function evaluateBoard(player) {
    // Some pre-calculated values for each rack position, based on the
    // number of possible 4-in-a-rows a position could theoretically be part of
    var values = [
        [ 3,  4,   5,  5,  4,  3 ],
        [ 4,  6,   8,  8,  6,  4 ],
        [ 5,  8,  11, 11,  8,  5 ],
        [ 7,  10, 13, 13, 10,  7 ],
        [ 5,  8,  11, 11,  8,  5 ],
        [ 4,  6,   8,  8,  6,  4 ],
        [ 3,  4,   5,  5,  4,  3 ]
    ];

    var patterns = {
        '2 connected, empty on the left': {
            rx: /__#{2}[^#_]/g,
            value: 10
        },
        '2 connected, empty on the right': {
            rx: /[^#_]#{2}__/g,
            value: 10
        },
        '2 connected, empty on both sides': {
            rx: /_#{2}_/g,
            value: 20
        },
        '3 connected, empty on the left': {
            rx: /_#{3}/g,
            value: 50
        },
        '3 connected, empty on the right': {
            rx: /#{3}_/g,
            value: 50
        },
        '3 connected, empty middle left': {
            rx: /#_#{2}/g,
            value: 50
        },
        '3 connected, empty middle right': {
            rx: /#{2}_#/g,
            value: 50
        },
        '3 connected, empty on both sides': {
            rx: /_#{3}_/g,
            value: 100
        }
    };

    var views = [
        getSouthView(player),
        getEastView(player),
        getSouthWestView(player),
        getSouthEastView(player)
    ];

    var score = 0;
    $.each(views, function(i, view) {

        var player_view = view.replace(/X/g, '#');
        var opponent_view = view.replace(/O/g, '#');

        if (opponent_view.match(/#{4}/)) {
            score = -Infinity;
            return false;
        }

        if (player_view.match(/#{4}/)) {
            score = Infinity;
            return false;
        }

        $.each(patterns, function(name, pattern) {
            var matches = player_view.match(pattern.rx);
            if (matches) {
                score += matches.length * pattern.value;
            }

            matches = opponent_view.match(pattern.rx);
            if (matches) {
                score -= matches.length * pattern.value;
            }
        });
    });

    return score;
}


function isCell(c, r) {
    return 0 <= c && c < _columns && 0 <= r && r < _rows;
}


function getCellChar(c, r, player) {
    var cell = _rack[c][r];
    if (cell === _player) {
        return 'X';
    } else if (cell) {
        return 'O';
    }
    return '_';
}


/* ################################################################################
    VIEWS
################################################################################ */

function getEastView(player) {
    var a = [];
    for (var r = 0; r < _rows; r++) {
        a.push('\n');
        for (var c = 0; c < _columns; c++) {
            a.push(getCellChar(c, r, player));
        }
    }
    return a.join('') + '\n';
}


function getSouthView(player) {
    var a = [];
    for (var c = 0; c < _columns; c++) {
        a.push('\n');
        for (var r = 0; r < _rows; r++) {
            a.push(getCellChar(c, r, player));
        }
    }
    return a.join('') + '\n';
}


function getSouthWestView(player) {
    var c = 0;
    var r = 0;
    var max = _columns * _rows;
    var counter = 0;
    var a = [];
    a.push('\n');
    while (counter != max) {
        if (isCell(c, r)) {
            var cell = _rack[c][r];
            a.push(getCellChar(c, r, player));
            counter++;
            c++;
            r--;
        } else if (r < 0) {
            a.push('\n');
            r = c;
            c = 0;
        } else {
            c++;
            r--;
        }
    }
    return a.join('') + '\n';
}


function getSouthEastView(player) {
    var c = _columns - 1;
    var r = 0;
    var max = _columns * _rows;
    var counter = 0;
    var a = [];
    a.push('\n');
    while (counter != max) {
        if (isCell(c, r)) {
            var cell = _rack[c][r];
            a.push(getCellChar(c, r, player));
            counter++;
            c--;
            r--;
        } else if (r < 0) {
            a.push('\n');
            r = _columns - c - 1;
            c = _columns - 1;
        } else {
            c--;
            r--;
        }
    }
    return a.join('') + '\n';
}


    _game.on('waitingForDrop', findAndPlayMove);
};
```

Comment: This is just JavaScript code. Are you asking how you package a...Node.js app?...into a Docker container?

Comment: yes pretty much I was told to create a standalone app for it

Comment: I'd base off of a container [like this](https://hub.docker.com/_/node).

Comment: ok thx what do i do with this to get it to work for me

Comment: We can't walk you through every single step here. You'll need to familiarize yourself with how `docker` and `Dockerfile` works, but there's *heaps* of material on that subject.

Comment: ok ill try to get a hang of it.

Comment: Get Docker, get an introduction, keep the [reference material open](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) as you learn and work on it. On the whole it's kind of weird, but not that hard, at least not compared to other build tools like Ansible or Chef.

Comment: ok ill do that (i was just asking cus im kinda in a hurry to get this complete)

Comment: is there a tutorial you can recommend that can help me get the job done

Comment: This is what search engines are for. Look for things like "dev.to build node app container docker".

Comment: thx for the tutorial